# How to start the user firmware after the bootloader firmware has finished in a Cortex-M3?

Tags: bootloader, firmware, cortex-m, cortex-m3

I'm trying to figure out the sequence of booting between bootloader and user firmware in the Cortex-M3. The Cortex-M3 design supports basic examples such as "Hello".

Here is the snippet for hello.c of user firmware code:

```
int main(void) 
{
  UartStdOutInit();
  printf("Hellow Test");
  printf("Test Passed");
  UartEndSimulation();
  return 0;
}
```

And here is bootloader.c:

```
_asm void FlashLoader(void)
{
  MOVS R0, #0
  LDR R1, [R0]
  MOV SP, R1
  LDR R1,[R0, #4[
  BX R1
}

int main(void) 
{
  UartStdOutInit();
  UartPuts("Boot Loader");
  UartPuts("load flash");
  FlashLoader();
  return 0;
}
```

As I know, the main sequence of bootloader is that it gets the initial MSP and PC value, and then branches to the R1 address which is the Reset_Handler of the bootloader.

But I'm confused about how the "bootloader" firmware finishes and how the "Hello" firmware magically starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence of booting between the bootloader and the user firmware on a Cortex-M3 microcontroller typically follows these steps:

1. The microcontroller is powered on or reset.
2. The bootloader code is loaded into memory and executed.
3. The bootloader checks for a valid user firmware image in
   non-volatile memory (e.g. flash memory).
4. If a valid user firmware image is found, the bootloader copies it
   from non-volatile memory into RAM and executes it.
5. If a valid user firmware image is not found, the bootloader waits
   for a new firmware image to be uploaded via a communication
   interface (e.g. UART, USB, Ethernet).

Here is an example of bootloader code in C that performs these steps:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "memory.h"  // Memory mapping and manipulation functions
#include "flash.h"   // Flash memory functions
#include "uart.h"    // UART communication functions

#define FIRMWARE_ADDRESS  0x08000000  // Address of firmware in flash memory
#define FIRMWARE_SIZE     0x4000      // Size of firmware in bytes

int main(void)
{
  uint8_t buffer[FIRMWARE_SIZE];  // Buffer for storing firmware image
  int i;

  // Check if valid firmware image is present in flash memory
  if (flash_verify(FIRMWARE_ADDRESS, FIRMWARE_SIZE, buffer))
  {
    // Copy firmware image from flash memory to RAM
    for (i = 0; i < FIRMWARE_SIZE; i++)
    {
      *((uint8_t*)(FIRMWARE_ADDRESS + i)) = buffer[i];
    }

    // Jump to firmware
    ((void(*)(void))FIRMWARE_ADDRESS)();
  }
  else
  {
    // Wait for firmware image to be uploaded via UART
    uart_init();
    uart_puts("Waiting for firmware image...\n");
    while (1)
    {
      if (uart_gets(buffer, FIRMWARE_SIZE))
      {
        // Erase flash memory
        flash_erase(FIRMWARE_ADDRESS, FIRMWARE_SIZE);

        // Write firmware image to flash memory
        flash_write(FIRMWARE_ADDRESS, FIRMWARE_SIZE, buffer);

        // Jump to firmware
        ((void(*)(void))FIRMWARE_ADDRESS)();
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This is just one example of how a bootloader might work. There are many different ways to implement a bootloader, and the specific details will depend on the specific microcontroller and the requirements of the application.

As for a "Hello" firmware example, here is some simple firmware code in C that will print "Hello, World!" to a UART interface:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "uart.h"  // UART communication functions

int main(void)
{
  uart_init();  // Initialize UART
  printf("Hello, World!\n");  // Print message to UART
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I update my hello.lst and bootload.lst for more question?

Comment: @Carter of course.